# How can I sum binned time series using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I want a simple graph like:

[image: financial graph]

The data I have is a simple list of transactions with two properties:

- timestamp
- amount

I tried d3.layout.histogram().bins() but it seems it only supports *counting* the transactions.

I mustn't be the only one looking for that, am I ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so the IRC folks helped me out and pointed to `nest`, which works great (this is CoffeeScript):

```
nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key((d) -> d3.time.day(d.timestamp))
  .rollup((a) -> d3.sum(a, (d) -> d.amount))
  .entries(incoming_data)  # An array of {timestamp: ..., amount: ...} objects

# Optional
nested_data.map (d) ->
  d.date = new Date(d.key)
```

The trick here is `d3.time.day` which takes a timestamp, and tells you which day (12 a.m. in the night) that timestamp belongs to.  This function and the other ones like `d3.time.week`, etc.. can bin timeseries very well.

The other trick is the `nest().rollup()` function, which after being grouped by `key()`, sum all of the events on a given `day`.

Last thing I wanted, was to interpolate empty values on the days where I had no transactions.  This is the last part of the code:

```
# Interpolate empty vals
nested_data.sort((a, b) -> d3.descending(a.date, b.date))
ex = d3.extent(nested_data, (d) -> d.date)
each_day = d3.time.days(ex[0], ex[1])

# Build a hashmap with the days we have
data_hash = {}
angular.forEach(data, (d) ->
  data_hash[d.date] = d.values
)

# Build a new array for each day, including those where we didn't have transactions
new_data = []
angular.forEach(each_day, (d) ->
  val = 0
  if data_hash[d]
    val = data_hash[d]
  new_data.push({date: d, values: val})
)

final_data = new_data
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

The histogram code doesn't support this, but you can easily do the binning yourself. Assuming that you have a date and a count for each transaction, you can bin by day like this.

```
var bins = {};
transactions.forEach(function(t) {
    var key = t.date.toDateString();
    bins[key] = bins[key] || 0;
    bins[key] += t.amount;
});
```

You can obviously parse the date string back into a date if you need it; the point of using `.toDateString()` here is that the time part is chopped off and everything binned by day. If you want to bin by another time interval, you can use the same technique and extract a different part of the date.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually a fast way to do it.  I'd probably use `d3.time.day` instead of toDateString() here.. so I could easily switch to different bin sizes by using `d3.time.week` or so.