# D3.js focus + context via brushing

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn d3.js focus + context via brushing using Twitter Data Analysis. I'm trying to generate the time series plot from the data given, but it's not coming up as it should. I have created fiddle. Could someone please take a look at it, and give me a suggestion on how I can fix this?

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
        margin2 = { top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
        y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
        xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(x2)
        .on("brush", brushed);

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

    var area2 = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
        .y0(height2)
        .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

    var svg = d3.select(".trend-graph").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id","clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var context = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "context")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

    d3.csv("/TwitterProject/slides/results.csv", type, function(error, data){

        x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.count; }))])
        x2.domain(x.domain());
        y2.domain(y.domain());

        focus.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d", area);

        focus.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        focus.append("g")
            .attr("class","y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        context.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class","area")
            .attr("d", area2);

        context.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
            .call(xAxis2);

        context.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x brush")
            .call(brush)
        .selectAll("rect")
            .attr("y", -6)
            .attr("height", height2 + 7);

    });

    function brushed(){

        x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
        focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
        focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }

    function type(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.count = +d.count;     
        return d;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6d8xsuz/)

Also, the y-axis is showing up wrong. I think the problem is somewhere counting the "counts" per minute, but I couldn't figure out how to fix this.

The plot is supposed to look like this.

[image]

EDIT:

Changes I made:

```
var bins = {};

x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
//y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.count; }))]).
y.domain([0, bins]).range([height, 0]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain()).range([height2, 0]);

function type(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.count = +d.count;     
    var key = d.date.toDateString();
    bins[key] = bins[key] || 0;
    bins[key] += d.count;
    console.log(bins);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, as in your data is plotted exactly as it is. You may want to consider binning it to get something more like the graph you want.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, Thanks for the reply. Since I'm new to d3.js, I'm not sure how to do binning. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408296/how-can-i-sum-binned-time-series-using-d3-js, but it's not clear to me what you did and what "transactions" is in my case.

Comment: The transactions there would be the tweets in your case.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I'm lost. I couldn't figure out how to setup bins. I tried a couple things, one of which is appended to the question as an EDIT. Could you please give me some pointers? I'm new to d3.js, and still have a whole lot to understand. I usually learn by doing more than reading the documentation, that's why I took this on to learn, but stuck in this thing. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Where are you calling `type`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, From d3.csv("path", type, function)

Comment: And `bins` contains what you expect it to contain?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I'm not sure. It seems like it contains all the date and time. I want the plot to display number of tweets per minute. In the original plot, the y-axis range is 0 to 140, mine is showing 4.0 which is the total count for a specific date and time. The plot should be for each minute. In the data, there are 63 tweets between 02:00 and 02:59 pm.

Comment: You need to do it differently for that. See http://jsfiddle.net/e6d8xsuz/2/ (along with a few other fixes).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, that's it. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Now I need some time to read and understand the code. Meanwhile, could you please add this as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has a resolution of one second, so you're going to get a very noisy graph (in fact exactly what you're getting). You probably want to do some binning, where you aggregate the data to make it less noisy.

In principle, the code looks like this (to aggregate by the minute):

```
function type(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.count = +d.count;
    d.date.setSeconds(0);
    var key = df(d.date);          
    bins[key] = bins[key] || 0;
    bins[key] += d.count;
    return d;
}
```

and then inside `d3.csv`:

```
var binData = d3.entries(bins);
    binData.forEach(function(d) { d.key = parseDate(d.key); });
    binData.sort(function(a,b) { return b.key - a.key; });
```

There's a bit of additional cruft because `Date` objects don't play nice as associative array keys. Now you have elements with `key` (date) and `value` in `binData`, which you can use to create the graph.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e6d8xsuz/2/).